# Cannot scan in the background

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

This is the code that is supposed to background scan according to the sample code in the altbeacon page, but this does not happen I don't even get the **Did enter region** tag. **RangingActivity**, which implements BeaconConsumer ranges beacons without any issue. The only log i see is **Background Scanning Initiated!** when i launch the application for the first time. Thanks in advance.

```
public class BackgroundScanner extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private String TAG="Background Scanner";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
private RangingActivity rangingActivity;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Background Scanning Initiated!");
    super.onCreate();
    BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            null, null, null);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000L);
    try {
        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
    sendNotification();
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification!")
                    .setContentText("Beacon Nearby!")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class));
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

}
```

Comment: It's better to put such background task in android Service, not in Application.

Comment: @PetrovDmitrii I wanted to do that first, but then i found out that this library provides the service already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library may think it is already in the region.  Starting with version 2.8, the library keeps track of region state across app restarts to prevent multiple `didEnterRegion` callbacks.  You can test this by turning off all beacons in the vicinity (or turning off Bluetooth) until you get a `didExitRegion` callback.  Then turn them back on and see if you get a `didEnterRegion` callback.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the issue i was facing.

Comment: You are not the first to run into this issue.  Do you think  there a way this could be more intuitive?

Comment: Now that you mention the issue, It makes so much sense this way.